# Check sheets name based on a range, if sheet not found then create new sheet with name from range

Tags: excel, vba, range, worksheet-function

I have a workbook with currently two sheets MI and Validation. Validation sheet column two have names, I need a code which should run ok opening the file and check if sheets are already created with all the names in column 2, for eg if there are 5 names from range B2:B7, then 5 sheets should be created, if sheet isn’t created then it should create new sheet with the name from name column. I tried few things but couldn’t succeeded, sorry can’t paste the code due to work Lap.

Tried vba code but can’t share due to work system.

Comment: what does _"Tried vba code but can’t share due to work system."_ mean?

Comment: I meant I made and tried some vba codes but can’t share those codes here as I work on company provided system.

Comment: still can't understand why you can't copy and paste your code here
It'd help you getting more help

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through the worksheet-names in column 2 of the "Validation" sheet and run a check if a sheet with that name already exists In the workbook. If the sheet doesn't exist, you can use the `.Add` method of the "Sheets" object to create a new sheet with the name from the current cell in the loop.

```
Sub CreateSheets()
    Dim wsValidation As Worksheet
    Set wsValidation = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Validation")

    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = wsValidation.Cells(wsValidation.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim sheetCount as Integer
    sheetCount = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 2 To lastRow
        Dim sheetName As String
        sheetName = wsValidation.Cells(i, 2).Value

        If Not ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sheetName) Is Nothing Then
            ' sheet already exists, do nothing or add an action to do if it does
        Else
            ' sheet doesn't exist, create it and add it after the last sheet
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sheetCount)).Name = sheetName
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```